# docker-compose error - Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-image

I'm trying to run docker-compose from /mnt/win/docker/
(I've changed the default docker directory for more space. Can't recall which file I configured in order to do it)

I get the following Error:

**ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile**

see *docker-compose.yml* below

I'm following wurstmeister/kafka-docker procedure:
ref1:[git wurstmeister](https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker)
ref2: [tutorial](http://wurstmeister.github.io/kafka-docker/)

```html
[liran@localhost docker]$ docker-compose --verbose up
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/liran/.docker/config.json', '/home/liran/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/liran/.docker/config.json', '/home/liran/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/version HTTP/1.1" 200 557
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe
docker-py version: 3.4.1
CPython version: 3.6.6
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: http+docker://localhost
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: Platform={'Name': ''}, Components=[{'Name': 'Engine', 'Version': '18.03.1-ce', 'Details': {'ApiVersion': '1.37', 'Arch': 'amd64', 'BuildTime': '2018-04-26T07:23:58.000000000+00:00', 'Experimental': 'false', 'GitCommit': '9ee9f40', 'GoVersion': 'go1.9.5', 'KernelVersion': '3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64', 'MinAPIVersion': '1.12', 'Os': 'linux'}}], Version=18.03.1-ce, ApiVersion=1.37, MinAPIVersion=1.12, GitCommit=9ee9f40, GoVersion=go1.9.5, Os=linux, Arch=amd64, KernelVersion=3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64, BuildTime=2018-04-26T07:23:58.000000000+00:00
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('docker_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/networks/docker_default HTTP/1.1" 200 443
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {'Attachable': False,
 'ConfigFrom': {'Network': ''},
 'ConfigOnly': False,
 'Containers': {},
 'Created': '2018-07-27T23:17:47.694667537+03:00',
 'Driver': 'bridge',
 'EnableIPv6': False,
 'IPAM': {'Config': [{'Gateway': '172.18.0.1', 'Subnet': '172.18.0.0/16'}],
          'Driver': 'default',
          'Options': None},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info <- ()
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/info HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker info -> {'Architecture': 'x86_64',
 'BridgeNfIp6tables': True,
 'BridgeNfIptables': True,
 'CPUSet': True,
 'CPUShares': True,
 'CgroupDriver': 'cgroupfs',
 'ClusterAdvertise': '',
 'ClusterStore': '',
 'ContainerdCommit': {'Expected': '773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88',
                      'ID': '773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88'},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network <- ('docker_default')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/networks/docker_default HTTP/1.1" 200 443
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_network -> {'Attachable': False,
 'ConfigFrom': {'Network': ''},
 'ConfigOnly': False,
 'Containers': {},
 'Created': '2018-07-27T23:17:47.694667537+03:00',
 'Driver': 'bridge',
 'EnableIPv6': False,
 'IPAM': {'Config': [{'Gateway': '172.18.0.1', 'Subnet': '172.18.0.0/16'}],
          'Driver': 'default',
          'Options': None},
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=docker', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddocker%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=docker', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=0&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddocker%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=docker', 'com.docker.compose.service=zookeeper', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddocker%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dzookeeper%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=docker', 'com.docker.compose.service=zookeeper', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddocker%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dzookeeper%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=docker', 'com.docker.compose.service=kafka', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddocker%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dkafka%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=docker', 'com.docker.compose.service=kafka', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/containers/json?limit=-1&all=1&size=0&trunc_cmd=0&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A+%5B%22com.docker.compose.project%3Ddocker%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.service%3Dkafka%22%2C+%22com.docker.compose.oneoff%3DFalse%22%5D%7D HTTP/1.1" 200 3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('wurstmeister/zookeeper')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/images/wurstmeister/zookeeper/json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image -> {'Architecture': 'amd64',
 'Author': 'Wurstmeister',
 'Comment': '',
 'Config': {'ArgsEscaped': True,
            'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': ['/bin/sh',
                    '-c',
                    '/usr/sbin/sshd && bash /usr/bin/start-zk.sh'],
...
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- ('docker_kafka')
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET /v1.22/images/docker_kafka/json HTTP/1.1" 404 64
compose.service.build: Building kafka
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (path='/mnt/win/docker', tag='docker_kafka', rm=True, forcerm=False, pull=False, nocache=False, dockerfile=None, cache_from=None, labels=None, buildargs={}, network_mode=None, target=None, shmsize=None, extra_hosts=None, container_limits={'memory': None}, gzip=False, isolation=None, platform=None)
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Looking for auth config
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: No auth config in memory - loading from filesystem
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths: ['/home/liran/.docker/config.json', '/home/liran/.dockercfg']
docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: No auth config found
urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "POST /v1.22/build?t=docker_kafka&q=False&nocache=False&rm=True&forcerm=False&pull=False HTTP/1.1" 500 47
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build -> <generator object APIClient._stream_helper at 0x7f9d213da0a0>
ERROR: compose.cli.errors.log_api_error: Cannot locate specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

```html
[liran@localhost docker]$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: [root@localhost docker]# find / -name Dockerfile
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied
/mnt/win/docker/overlay/98e3ecf24033c81f95599d19a64f3c900d7d61a6fdbe06ba91d97ddb1d6562cc/root/usr/share/docker.io/contrib/desktop-integration/data/Dockerfile
/mnt/win/docker/overlay/98e3ecf24033c81f95599d19a64f3c900d7d61a6fdbe06ba91d97ddb1d6562cc/root/usr/share/docker.io/contrib/desktop-integration/iceweasel/Dockerfile
/mnt/win/docker/overlay/08e655f6a90d07e4cc84d4a9b7fba9b81605dbd70b75fa82e98d41fff35ed051/root/usr/share/docker.io/contrib/desktop-integration/data/Dockerfile

Comment: you are not using the image of kafka but building it `  kafka: build: .` do you have the Dockerfile in the same location as `docker-compose.yml` ? Also why you not using the image?

Comment: Yes.
[liran@localhost docker]$ ll
total 9
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Jul 27 21:40 builder
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Jul 27 21:40 containerd
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Jul 27 21:40 containers
**-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  324 Jul 27 23:17 docker-compose.yml**
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Jul 27 21:40 image
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Jul 27 21:40 network
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 8192 Jul 27 23:40 overlay
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 Jul 27 21:40 plugins

I'm using the docker-compose because this is the procedure described in the docker-hub (see links in main post).

Answer (score 8):

above docker-compose file assumes that you have Dockerfile in same folder .
Change `build: .` --> `image: wurstmeister/kafka` in your docker-compose file .then it should work

Comment: Solved this issue for me :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems the related documentation is uncomplete. You've to download the github project, where there is the docker-compose.yml AND the rest of the files needed to be able to build the kafka docker image :

```
git clone https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker
cd kafka-docker
```

Modify the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME in docker-compose.yml to match your docker host IP

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing information on how and why it solves the problem improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

NTFS is not supported with OverlayFS storage driver.
Answered [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23930)